# How to get three plots from pandas plot into one figure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have massive CSV file which uses timeseries which spans 3 years and looks something like this:

```
   Date                   Company1       Company2
2020-01-01 00:00:00        100            200
2020-01-01 01:00:00        110            180
2020-01-01 02:00:00        90             210
2020-01-01 03:00:00        100            200
      ....                 ...            ...
2020-12-31 21:00:00        100            200
2020-12-31 22:00:00        80             230
2020-12-31 23:00:00        120            220
```

Except I have 10 companies.
Anyway, I managed to plot 3 plots for one month for each year, looks like this

```
newMatrix.plot(x='Date', y='Company4', xlim=('2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-31 23:00:00'))
newMatrix.plot(x='Date', y='Company4', xlim=('2021-01-01 00:00:00', '2021-01-31 23:00:00'))
newMatrix.plot(x='Date', y='Company4', xlim=('2022-01-01 00:00:00', '2022-01-31 23:00:00'))
```

Now the problem is that I can't figure out how to make one figure where I can see better how the trends differ between years (for example during January each year). The best outcome would be to have the days/months on the x axis and each plotted line representing each year.

I have been experimenting combining `matplotlib` with pandas plot, but so far I either get no plot or three figures. How can I solve this?

Comment: `df.plot` takes an `ax` argument that should contain the axes you want to plot into.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do something like this (keep in mind I don't have the entire df):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create DataFrame
data = {'Date': ['2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 01:00:00', '2020-01-01 02:00:00', '2020-01-01 03:00:00', '2020-12-31 21:00:00', '2020-12-31 22:00:00', '2020-12-31 23:00:00'],
        'Company1': [100, 110, 90, 100, 100, 80, 120],
        'Company2': [200, 180, 210, 200, 200, 230, 220]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=5, figsize=(15, 6), sharey=True)

for i, company in enumerate(df.columns):
    # create mask for January for each year
    mask_2020 = (df.index >= '2020-01-01') & (df.index <= '2020-01-31')
    mask_2021 = (df.index >= '2021-01-01') & (df.index <= '2021-01-31')
    mask_2022 = (df.index >= '2022-01-01') & (df.index <= '2022-01-31')

    axes[i//5, i%5].plot(df.loc[mask_2020, company], label='2020')
    axes[i//5, i%5].plot(df.loc[mask_2021, company], label='2021')
    axes[i//5, i%5].plot(df.loc[mask_2022, company], label='2022')
    axes[i//5, i%5].set_title(company)
    axes[i//5, i%5].legend()

fig.text(0.04, 0.5, 'Value', va='center', rotation='vertical')
fig.text(0.5, 0.04, 'Date', ha='center')
fig.suptitle('Company trends for January of each year')
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3, hspace=0.5)

plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: This is in the correct direction. I however I am currently only looking at one company, but if that changes, this is a great method. I might modify this to use with only one company. Just so you know, I am not allowed to share the  `df` by the company that provided me with it.